# Configuring ufw or iptables to allow only outbound traffic to the Internet from an internal IPv6 network

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, router, ipv6

How do I configure ufw or iptables to allow only outbound traffic from an IPv6 network to the Internet?

I have an office network with a traditional NAT setup for IPv4. I would like to add a PC running Ubuntu to act as an IPv6 router utilizing a tunnel from Hurricane Electric.

I have everything setup and functioning properly. My internal computers are receiving global addresses from the Ubuntu box and are able to ping ipv6.google.com and browse ipv6test.google.com without any problems.

**What I am not sure about, is how to configure a firewall to block incoming unsolicited traffic from the Internet to my internal network but allow outbound traffic to the Internet (and related return traffic).**

Actual examples of ufw commands or iptables rules would be greatly appreciated.

```
root@ipv6router:/home/corey# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:08:a1:10:62:c0  
          inet addr:146.x.y.12  Bcast:146.x.y.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::208:a1ff:fe10:62c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:190487 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:1 frame:1
          TX packets:40982 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:80088076 (80.0 MB)  TX bytes:6825762 (6.8 MB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:5b:f0:5b  
          inet addr:192.168.76.3  Bcast:192.168.76.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:fe5b:f05b/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:x:1f07:z::1/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:90200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59894 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12839775 (12.8 MB)  TX bytes:70668474 (70.6 MB)

he-ipv6   Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9273:130c/128 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:x:1f06:z::2/64 Scope:Global
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:56991 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:69388394 (69.3 MB)  TX bytes:4537403 (4.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:13137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:998616 (998.6 KB)  TX bytes:998616 (998.6 KB)

root@ipv6router:/home/corey# route -A inet6
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met  Ref Use If
2001:x:1f06:z::1/128           ::                         U    1024 0     1 he-ipv6
2001:x:1f06:z::/64             ::                         Un   256  0     0 he-ipv6
2001:x:1f07:z::/64             ::                         U    256  0     0 eth1
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256  0     0 eth1
fe80::/64                      ::                         Un   256  0     0 he-ipv6
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256  0     0 eth0
::/0                           2001:x:1f06:z::1           UG   1024 0     0 he-ipv6
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1   1 92337 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0    1   412 lo
2001:x:1f06:z::/128            ::                         Un   0    1     0 lo
2001:x:1f06:z::2/128           ::                         Un   0    1   736 lo
2001:x:1f07:z::/128            ::                         Un   0    1     0 lo
2001:x:1f07:z::1/128           ::                         Un   0    1     0 lo
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0    1     0 lo
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0    1     0 lo
fe80::9273:130c/128            ::                         Un   0    1     0 lo
fe80::208:a1ff:fe10:62c0/128   ::                         Un   0    1     0 lo
fe80::21b:21ff:fe5b:f05b/128   ::                         Un   0    1  4611 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256  0     0 eth1
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256  0     0 he-ipv6
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256  0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1   1 92337 lo
```

Comment: I don't have the rules for it, but what you're looking for is tracking of ESTABLISHED sessions.  NAT strictly translates addresses -- it has nothing to do with blocking traffic in either direction.  You want your server to allow return connections that are initiated from the inside, but block all other traffic.  I know this isn't an answer to your question, but wanted to clarify the terms you're using.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I removed the unnecessary reference to NAT.

Comment: It's not a proper answer, but with a little modification, these should help you: http://www.sixxs.net/wiki/IPv6_Firewalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `forward` chain to add forwarding firewall rules.

```
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i he-ipv6 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT # Accept already established connections (return traffic, for instance)
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i he-ipv6 -j DROP # Drop the rest
ip6tables -A FORWARD -o he-ipv6 -j ACCEPT # Accept outbound connections to the ipv6 tunnel
ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP # Set default policy on forward chain
```

With this setup you'll need to add a few more rules to let the other interfaces route how you want, but it's gonna end up very similar to the above.

Comment: would you happen to know on a Ubuntu box the best place/file to insert these lines?

Comment: The terminal would be the best place to enter commands. There's usually a prompt like this: `gp@iron:~$`

Comment: i meant is there a file that i could put them in to make them persistant

Comment: You can use the `iptables-persistent` package in Ubuntu. I think they're in `/etc/iptables/rules.v6`. You'll use `ip6tables-save` to do it.

Comment: that worked perfectly!